# Upgrade windows from 10 to 11

Tags: windows-10, windows-11

I can't upgrade win 10 to 11 on some user machines as they are getting blocked when trying to perform Health Checks.I guess this is due to the fact that all Updates are pushed from SCCM.
Is there a possibility for a workaround in this case, so I can upgrade win manually from the official Microsoft site?

I tried changing the register but that won't do anything.
Remove the Windows Update registry key by entering the command Remove-Item HKLM: \Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate -Recurse

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows 11 upgrade package must first be imported into SCCM by the administrator ([link](https://www.prajwaldesai.com/upgrade-to-windows-11-using-multiple-methods/#Method-3-Windows-11-Upgrade-SCCM-Configuration-Manager)).

Beware : Unauthorized upgrades of a company computer might be
sanctioned by the company.

Comment: “Might not be sanctioned” is I believe what Harry actually means.

Comment: @Ramhound: "Sanction" seems confusedly to have two meanings : "authorize" but also "punish" (as in "international sanctions"). I meant the second one.

Answer (score -1):

Use the update tool on the Microsoft website? Or open the setup.exe from the Windows 11 image, I remember it will provide a option to upgrade your pc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I use the Installation Assistant from MS website
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).